# Action Listener not working in second frame

Tags: java

Trying to get the Fire JButton to switch text to Locked In, but for some reason its not working please explain why. Any way to orginize this better too, Going from Main Menu to game.

```
/**
 * Auto Generated Java Class.
 */
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class FinalProject implements ActionListener {

  //Main menu values
  JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
  JTextField mainTitle = new JTextField();
  JButton play = new JButton();

  //Game values
  JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame();
  JTextField gameTopTitle = new JTextField();
  JTextField gameBottonTitle = new JTextField();
  JButton item = new JButton();
  JButton fire = new JButton();
  JButton leaveGame = new JButton();

  int fuel = 100;
  int power = 100;
  int angle = 100;


  public FinalProject(){

    //Frame Details
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setSize(900,700);
    mainFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(50,50,50));
    mainFrame.setLayout(null);
    mainFrame.setResizable(false);

    //Title
    mainTitle.setBounds(0,0,800,100); //bounds of the textfield
    mainTitle.setBackground(new Color(25,25,25)); //Color number
    mainTitle.setForeground(new Color(255,255,255)); //Color Number
    mainTitle.setFont(new Font("Ink Free",Font.BOLD,30)); //Font
    mainTitle.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1)); //Border
    mainTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER); //Center text
    mainTitle.setEditable(false); //Change whats inside textfield (False)

    //Buttons
    play.setBounds(200,200,250,100); //location
    play.setFont(new Font("MV Boli",Font.BOLD,35));
    play.setFocusable(false); //Hightlight button letter (False)
    play.addActionListener(this);
    play.setText("Play");

    //frame addons
    mainFrame.add(mainTitle);
    mainFrame.add(play);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
  }
  public void mainGame(){

    //Game Frame
    gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gameFrame.setSize(900,700);
    gameFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(50,50,50));
    gameFrame.setLayout(null);
    gameFrame.setResizable(false);
    //Game Title Botton
    gameBottonTitle.setBounds(0,585,900,5);
    gameBottonTitle.setBackground(new Color(25,25,25));
    gameBottonTitle.setForeground(new Color(255,255,255));
    gameBottonTitle.setFont(new Font("Ink Free",Font.BOLD,30));
    gameBottonTitle.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1));
    gameBottonTitle.setEditable(false);

    //Game Buttons Bottom
    fire.setBounds(450,590,150,70);
    fire.setFont(new Font("MV Boli",Font.BOLD,35));
    fire.setFocusable(false);
    fire.addActionListener(this);
    fire.setText("Fire");

    item.setBounds(130,590,150,70);
    item.setFont(new Font("MV Boli",Font.BOLD,35));
    item.setFocusable(false);
    item.addActionListener(this);
    item.setText("Items");

    leaveGame.setBounds(740,590,150,70);
    leaveGame.setFont(new Font("MV Boli",Font.PLAIN,20));
    leaveGame.setFocusable(false);
    leaveGame.addActionListener(this);
    leaveGame.setText("Leave Game");



    gameFrame.setVisible(true);
    gameFrame.add(gameBottonTitle);
    gameFrame.add(fire);
    gameFrame.add(item);
    gameFrame.add(leaveGame);

  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    if(e.getSource()==play){
      mainFrame.setVisible(false);
      play.setEnabled(false);
      mainGame();

      if(e.getSource()==fire){
        fire.setText("Locked In");
      }
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    FinalProject mainFrame = new FinalProject();
  }
}
```

Also Trying to figure out how to make an arc that gets smaller when it gets closer and velocity affecting its height also an object following in its path in a loop The arc has to be in a loop so when any angle is selected and any velocity is selected it creates the arc trail for the object to move as a path like an artillery motion, as u adjust the barrel it creates an arc shape shot - More power meaning higher velocity+height+width. But I'm not sure how to animate it in a arc shape as the shot moves.